# How to sign based on data, but verify based on hash in Java?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography

How can I calculate an RSA signature based on data but verify that signature based on the data's hash (and/or vice versa)? Signing/verifying *data* internally just hashes that data and then operates on the hash, and on other platforms I can accomplish this. But in Java I can't seem to configure the signing algorithm correctly, I guess.

How can I verify the signature using just the hash of the data?

Here is what I have:

```
import java.security.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[] {1,2,3};

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        digest.update(data);
        byte[] sha1Hash = digest.digest();

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(512);
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

        Signature signingInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signingInstance.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        signingInstance.update(data);
        byte[] signature = signingInstance.sign();

        Signature dataVerifyingInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        dataVerifyingInstance.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
        dataVerifyingInstance.update(data);
        boolean dataVerified = dataVerifyingInstance.verify(signature);

        Signature hashVerifyingInstance = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
        hashVerifyingInstance.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
        hashVerifyingInstance.update(sha1Hash);
        boolean hashVerified = hashVerifyingInstance.verify(signature);

        System.out.println("Verification based on data: " + dataVerified);
        System.out.println("Verification based on hash: " + hashVerified);
    }
}
```

The output of running this program is:

```
Verification based on data: true
Verification based on hash: false
```

Comment: Why don't you sign the hash instead?

Comment: I could. But as one party signs and the other party verifies, each party should be able to independently choose how to sign or verify the data.

Comment: Why? All parties should agree on how the data is signed, verified, hashed, encrypted, formatted, stored and anything else.

Comment: The point is it's supposed to be independent of the protocol. There is no reason for parties to have to agree whether to sign the hash itself or hash-sign the data, because it comes to the same thing. The code I have _should work_. It does on other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (formally named [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-41)) to be constructed around the hash value first. Only after that will the trick with `"NONEwithRSA"` work.

You may cheat and look at the sources of BouncyCastle or the GPL version of Java of course. Alternatively you could use the BouncyCastle lightweight API, but you would loose compatibility with JCA and add a dependency.

`JavaCard` does have functions for creating the hash off-card. This kind of functionality is not needed as much in libraries intended to run on a full featured PC (and I did not find it in the Java 7 classes either).

Comment: History: Back in the day v1.5 (for signing or the different one for encryption) was the only padding mode used in the industry standard PKCS#1 document. So RSA for signature generation was simply called "[HASH]withRSA" while it actually is "[HASH]withPKCSV1_5andRSA". The newer/better PSS scheme complicates this by adding configuration options.

Comment: That would explain when I "encrypted" the signature with the public key, I discovered the hash value at index 16 in the result. That's consistent with the doc you linked to. Thanks.